# How to separate languages in Django Model / Database

Tags: python, database, django, model, internationalization

In my Django Project I am using the i18n internationalization to translate all templates. Now, depending on the chosen language I also would like to separate the data that users are submitting to the database. I do not want to have mixed languages in one table. What is the best approach how to solve this problem? I am developing using Django 1.5.2.

Comment: So you'll have a different database for each language with the same models?

Comment: My question is if I really need different databases or if I can just use one database with multiple models like e.g. `MyModel_en` and `MyModel_de`

Comment: I think that models with slightly different names tend to chaos. If you want multiple databases with the same model names you should take a look at [database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers).

Answer (score 2):

I have alreay made a project like this. I have used one table with mixed languages, with a column to specify which language it is. I have no problem with this implementation.

An other approach I had thought is to create dynamically a table like content_ and to fill in. But very boring (you have to manage id dependancy with other tables) and not necessary for me.

Have you got a fixed number language ?

Comment: At the moment I have only two languages. But in future there should be added further languages. So I will need a generic solution that will be easy to extend by other languages.

Comment: If the number of language is limited, you can only create a column per language. If you add a new language, it's eaysy to add a new column. It's the best solution I think

Answer (score 0):

I don't know really what 's best way. 
You can serialize a dictionary, for example save this dic in your database:

```
{
  'en': 'Book',
  'ge': 'booch',
  ...
}
```